# Should I use Jquery to click toggle instead of React?

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I often heard that it is bad idea to combine react and jquery but I think it is more easier for me to make change on DOM with jQuery

Example:

```
 <a className="toggleLink">Click Here to toggle Menu</li>
 <div className="contentToToggle">content to toggle</div>
```

For jquery, I will write to function extend then I can use again for many cases or I can use click event directly by class. This class will also used again.

```
jQuery.fn.extend({
  toggle: function(element){...}
});
```

but in react, I feel quite complex, each click on each component, I have to make a state to return for that component only. 
Expose that I have 10 click events: First to toggle, second to addClass, third for showing popup...
So it should be bad idea to use React in this case. Is it right?

I want someone here can help me with this situation. Thanks

Comment: You can handle click easily with reactjs by playing with state to get toggle!, I agree, it's bad idea to use jQuery on React

Comment: Is your application requires reactjs, because if you have the usecase only then use it like for example if you have frequent updates of dom. If it is able to achieve by jquery then you can use it and its too lightweight apart from whatever framework or library we use the last base is javascript itself. And If you can explain whats your use case then we will be able to find a better solution for you from our knowledge. So reading through what i find is basically a div on each click of different buttons to inside the div you need to perfom diff actions is that what you are looking for !!

Comment: well, thank you all. I see it now.

Answer (score 3):

It is always preferred to not mix React and JQuery and it might make things more complicated.

Both of them have different ideologies. **JQuery modifies actual DOM** whereas **React plays around with Virtual DOM.**

Coding things with React may seem little bit heavy and cumbersome initially but it keeps things much more clear and less abstract going forward. Hope this helps !

Answer (score 0):

No no no no no and some more no

They are two different approaches to building a web app. Using JQuery means React could no longer be handling state, events and UI rendering. Which can causes conflicts, almost like two builders trying to build the same road at the same time using different materials and approaches.

If you using React you should use React's approach to manipulating and updating the DOM. That being said you don't have to use React if you don't want to. If you're familiar with JQuery build the site the way you know how if that will get it done quicker and React is not a requirement.